# Sequence, convergence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the sequence, $E_{n=0}^∞ (\exp\{-(E_n)/((k_B)T)\})$ is convergent and find its sum.

I usually know how to do this with other functions, but I feel kind of lost in this one since it is an exponential function with different variables?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$?  What is $E_n$?

Comment: Yes I do, it says that E_n is the energy. It says E_n = E_0 +2nE_0 where E_0 is a constant, and k_B is boltzman's constant = 0.67

Comment: Are $E_0$ and $T$ positive?  Hint: geometric series.

Comment: I don't really know, I suppose T (temperature) would be positive, but I had guessed it would be a geometric series, but I can't figure out how to come to any conclusion. I guess one could assume that both the energy and temperature would be positive, but then we would have exponetial to something negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e^{\frac{-E_0}{k_B T}} = r$. Note that $r<1$.

Then
\begin{align}
\sum_0^{\infty} e^{\frac{-E_0(1+2n)}{k_B T}} &= \sum_0^{\infty} r^{1+2n} \\
&= r\sum_0^{\infty} r^{2n} \\
&= \frac{r}{1-r^2} \\
&= \frac{e^{\frac{-E_0}{k_B T}}}{1-e^{\frac{-2E_0}{k_B T}}} \\
\end{align}